# How do I test a webm videostream using jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, streaming, load-testing, webm

AFAIK there are 2 video streaming plugins available for JMeter:

- BlazeMeter - HLS Plugin and
- UbikLoadPack Video Streaming plugin

UbikLoadPack as a prohibitive pricing tag and HLS Plugin doesn't test the format I need. Also I want a FOSS solution not a paid one.

Does anyone know of some other plugin or method I could test a webm video stream ?

**Edit**

@dmitri-t when I try to do this it just hangs. [Here](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-video-streaming-with-jmeter-learn-how) I found [this](https://github.com/raladev/load/tree/master/Streaming/ProgressiveDownload) script that shows how to test a video. But when I changed the parameters to my video and range to 0-100 it hanged.
Also the example is using HTTP and my video uses HTTPS.

Tried to include a timer. It hangs also.

Yet the video loads perfectly in Chrome with the same url I used in Jmeter.

I also tested the request with Postman. It ignores the range header. So what's probably happening in JMeter is that it's trying to load the whole continuous stream. How do I make it consider range header ?

I tested with Postman on an image in the same server to see if range header was being considered or if it was a server problem and range was respected correctly.

Content-Range header doesn't work also. Please check this related question I did relative to the range problem with streams: [Request to a webm stream ignores range header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69667832/request-to-a-webm-stream-ignores-range-header)

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you need any form of plugin, you can simulate the browser playing the video using normal [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler sending simple [HTTP GET](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET) request

Here is the evidence that "playing" an webm "stream" is nothing more than downloading it.

[image]

It would be a good idea to add [Timers](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/comprehensive-guide-using-jmeter-timers/) to simulate users watching the video till the end (or according to your test case)

Comment: see my edit in the question

Comment: What do you expect from me? To visit your question daily to see whether you "edited" something and if there are no links to other questions (which are not related to the original one by any means)? If you need to request partial video - use [Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Range) header via [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager/). If your server doesn't respect the Range header - it's not a JMeter problem.

Comment: The Range header on HTTP Header Manager doesn't work for continuous flows. Only for fixed length videos and fixed lengths resources. It's not the server that isn't respecting it. I use Apache. Test it outside JMeter in Postman or Imnsonia and you'll see.

Comment: I didn't mean to be "rude" to you in particular or whoever in general, I do apologize if it sounds offensive. In order to help you further we need an example of an "endless webm stream" (I tried to search one and failed)