# Request to a webm stream ignores range header

Tags: stream, http-headers, webm

I'm using postman to test a continous webm videostream. But the range request is being ignored.

If I try using an image in the same server, range works ok. If I try it on as fixed length video it works ok.

This link has the fixed webm video I tested and worked: https://github.com/rubu/WebMPlayer/blob/master/Samples/big_buck_bunny_live.webm?raw=true

I can't provide the specific continuous stream I'm using because it's a corporative asset. Nor I was able to find any webm streams live on the web

Anyone knows how I can make range work for streams ? If someone knows any continuous webm stream that we could use as a test here it would also be helpful.

What I want is to generate a request that I can use in JMeter to include in a load test. So if someone can demonstrate how to do this request that loads a small amount of a continuous web stream in JMeter the answer is valid too.

Comment: Isn't the point of an infinite WEBM stream that the client connects, gets some startup metadata and then ... an infinite stream of video from that moment in time? So I highly doubt any video server to support range requests in that scenario, because you can't retrieve the next frame, segment, whatever, because by the time you can issue that request, that range doesn't exist on the server anymore. What you _seem_ to want is if you issue a request to that particular server, confirm that it responds with _a_ chunk of video, and then you want to disconnect, right?

Comment: @CodeCaster yes. That's right. Do you have any other way to do that besides range ?

Answer (score 0):

You can see that accepting ranges is a server-side configuration as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/720419/how-can-i-find-out-whether-a-server-supports-the-range-header)

You'll see that in a less public server (than GitHub) you will be able to send a GET request and receive a `Accept-Ranges: bytes` so it depends on the configuration.

My working example is illustrated here :

[image]

**NB :** As stated in [RFC7233's Intro](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7233#section-1) this is only possible with GET requests.